# What flag to be match for question to close?

Tags: discussion

Should [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008556/self-hosting-localization-tools-for-ios-android) question to be close as

```
Search on Other site or recommended books
```

Comment: How can a question be closed as "not a valid *answer*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one.

The second one is meant for answers. Such a question *lends itself* to such answers, though, so flagging answers to such a question is unnecessary at best and a waste of your flags and our time at worst.

Comment: Ok but what about an answer then?? I think `not an answer` is valid flag for that.